# How to open a screen with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a tabbed view with three tabs based on RNE (React native elements demo app). [image]I had to disable the drawernavigator from the middle tab because it doesn't work to click a link in the drawer and then click the drawer again back to the middle tab view because then it crashes. From the left and right tab it works and I can't understand why this is the case. I'm just trying to open a view but since I am using react navigation it doesn't work. I use a fancy *DrawerNavigator*, a cool *TabNavigator* and a nifty *StackNavigator* instead of keeping it simple and I get error message trying to navigate from the DrawerNavigator to the TabNavigator.

The App.js

```
/**
 * React Native App
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, Image, Dimensions, AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems,NavigationActions  } from 'react-navigation';


import Components from './src/drawer/components';
import Ratings from './src/drawer/ratings';
import Pricing from './src/drawer/pricing';
import Login from './src/drawer/login';
import Profile from './src/drawer/profile';
import Lists from './src/drawer/lists';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => {

    return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#43484d' }}>
        <View
            style={{ marginTop: 40, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
        >
            <Image
                source={require('./src/images/logo.png')}
                style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.57 }}
                resizeMode="contain"
            />
        </View>
        <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </View>
    </View>
)};

const MainRoot = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        Login: {
            path: '/login',
            screen: Login
        },
        Profile: {
             path: '/profile',
             screen: Profile
         },
      /*  Lists: {
             path: '/lists',
             screen: Lists
         },*/
        Components: {
            path: '/components',
            screen: Components,
        },
    /*    Ratings: {
            path: '/ratings',
            screen: Ratings,
        },*/
        Pricing: {
            path: '/pricing',
            screen: Pricing,
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Components',
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#548ff7',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            inactiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 15,
                marginLeft: 0,
            },
        },
        drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8,
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,

        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
        drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
        drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
    }
);
export default MainRoot;
```

My drawer navigator.

```
/**
 * React Native App
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, Image, Dimensions, AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';


import Components from './src/drawer/components';
import Ratings from './src/drawer/ratings';
import Pricing from './src/drawer/pricing';
import Login from './src/drawer/login';
import Profile from './src/drawer/profile';
import Lists from './src/drawer/lists';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#43484d' }}>
        <View
            style={{ marginTop: 40, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
        >
            <Image
                source={require('./src/images/logo.png')}
                style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.57 }}
                resizeMode="contain"
            />
        </View>
        <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </View>
    </View>
);
const CustomDrawerContentComponent2 = (props) => {
    const nav = props.nav;

    return (<View>
        <ScrollView>
            <DrawerItems
                {...props}
                onItemPress = {
                    ({ route, focused }) =>
                    {
                        props.onItemPress({ route, focused })
                        console.log("item pressed");
                    }
                }
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>)
};
const MainRoot = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        Login: {
            path: '/login',
            screen: Login
        },
        Profile: {
             path: '/profile',
             screen: Profile
         },
        Lists: {
             path: '/lists',
             screen: Lists
         },
        Components: {
            path: '/components',
            screen: Components,
        },
    /*    Ratings: {
            path: '/ratings',
            screen: Ratings,
        },*/
        Pricing: {
            path: '/pricing',
            screen: Pricing,
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Components',
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#548ff7',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            inactiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 15,
                marginLeft: 0,
            },
        },
        drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8,
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,

        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
        drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
        drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
    }
);
export default MainRoot;
```

My Tab Navigator.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import ButtonsTab from '../tabs/buttons';
import ListsTab from '../tabs/lists';
import InputTab from '../tabs/input';
import FontsTab from '../tabs/fonts';
import DetailedTrends from '../views/lists_home'
const Components = TabNavigator(
  {
    ButtonsTab: {
      screen: ButtonsTab,
      path: '/buttons',
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Add',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon
            name={focused ? 'camera' : 'camera'}
            size={30}
            type="material-community"
            color={tintColor}
          />
        ),
      },
    },
    ListsTab: {
      screen: ListsTab,
      path: '/lists',
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Ads',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon name="list" size={30} type="entypo" color={tintColor} />
        ),
      },
    },

   /* FontsTab: {
      screen: FontsTab,
      path: '/fonts',
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'On map',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon
            name={focused ? 'map-marker-outline' : 'map-marker-outline'}
            size={30}
            type="material-community"
            color={tintColor}
          />
        ),
      },
    },*/
      InputTab: {
          screen: InputTab,
          path: '/input',
          navigationOptions: {
              tabBarLabel: 'My activity',
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                  <Icon
                      name={focused ? 'emoticon-cool' : 'emoticon-neutral'}
                      size={30}
                      type="material-community"
                      color={tintColor}
                  />
              ),
          },
      },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ListsTab',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    // Android's default option displays tabBars on top, but iOS is bottom
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
      // Android's default showing of icons is false whereas iOS is true
      showIcon: true,
    },
  }
);

Components.navigationOptions = {
  drawerLabel: 'Components',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <Icon
      name="settings"
      size={30}
      iconStyle={{
        width: 30,
        height: 30
      }}
      type="material"
      color={tintColor}
    />
  ),
};

export default Components;
```

If I now press "Components" in the Drawer Navigator to navigate to the components view, my app crashes.

"There is no route defined for key ButtonsTab."

What is the purpose of this error?

How can I troubleshoot this? Why is it complaining about ButtonsTab?

```
Error: There is no route defined for key ButtonsTab.
Must be one of: 'Home','Lists_Detail'

This error is located at:
    in DrawerView (at DrawerNavigator.js:88)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
    in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
getScreenForRouteName
```

If I add a navigator to lists.js it almost works but still incomprehensible, unnecessary and wrong. Why do they make a framework where you can't navigate between screens?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import ListsHome from '../views/lists_home';
import ListsDetails from '../views/lists_detail';
import ButtonsTab from '../tabs/buttons';

const ListsTabView = ({ navigation }) => (
  <ListsHome banner="Lists" navigation={navigation} />
);

const ListsDetailTabView = ({ navigation }) => (
  <ListsDetails banner="Lists Detail" navigation={navigation} />
);

const ListsTab = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: ListsTabView,
    path: '/',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Lists',
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon
          name="menu"
          size={30}
          type="entypo"
          style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        />
      ),
    }),
  },
  Lists_Detail: {
    screen: ListsDetailTabView,
    path: 'lists_detail',
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Lists Detail',
    },
  },  ButtonsTab: {
        screen: ListsTabView,
        path: '/',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'Lists',
            headerLeft: (
                <Icon
                    name="menu"
                    size={30}
                    type="entypo"
                    style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
                />
            ),
        }),
    },

});

export default ListsTab;
```

Comment: Please share your drawer navigator code also, and from where are you trying access tab navigator?

Comment: @ParasWatts I put in the drawer navigator code. It is code from RNE react native elements. that reference project seems to havae the same problem. Can't click on "components" if navigated _from_ a tabbed view in the stack.

Comment: I am sharing with you a sample I made using stack navigator , tab navigator and drawer navigator

Comment: https://github.com/paraswatts/DrawerNavigatorReactNative

Comment: @ParasWatts Couldn't even start it and I can't really start over just because a link is not working.

Comment: Delete node_modules folder, then run npm install command and then start the project using react-native-start

Comment: @ParasWatts I'm trying for the fourth time to install your project. Now I have two problems: My app crashes and I can't install your project.

Comment: What are the steps that you have followed to run my project ?

Comment: @ParasWatts I tried everything. Right now I am trying to disable the drawernavigator for certain screens. That doesn't work either. All I am trying to do is basically reset the navigation but that will not work. I have been trying for days to achieve this simple thing.

Comment: Check other projects in my repo, I have two other projects on react-navigation

Comment: @ParasWatts Ok. I also try to read this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/973 because if I can reset the stack then I think it will work. I found the same bug in two independent apps. Navigating using the drawer when a middle tab is open crashes the apps.

Comment: @ParasWatts After a few attempts I could run your project with a drawer. You are right, it does what I want and correctly. It doesn't crash like the other apps do. Thanks! Now I can base my code on your project and get what I want.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @ParasWatts You solved a really important problem for us. I was trying since Saturday to make it work. If you convert your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sample project which I made to demonstrate `StackNavigator`, `TabNavigator` and `DrawerNavigator` working together.

[github.com/paraswatts/DrawerNavigatorReactNative](http://github.com/paraswatts/DrawerNavigatorReactNative)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sir, do you have any drawerNavigation React Native Example App that implement with Redux?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any example with redux